# Is CDO Email the best way to send email using classic asp?

Tags: email, asp-classic, cdo.message

I am using asp to create a webpage that is supposed to send email to several clients.  It was suggested that I use CDO email functionality.  Is this the best solution for a classic asp webpage?  Or would it be better to add asp.net and ajax for handling email this type of thing.

Comment: I don't see a reason to tag this VB6 or VB6-migration.

Comment: It would be better to do *anything* in ASP.NET.

Comment: I can perform CDO Mail fine in vb6, but its not working with asp.

Comment: Related question:   [send email in classic ASP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772033/sending-mail-code-in-asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDO would be the obvious route.  In some versions of the .Net Framework ASP.Net would just be using a wrapper around CDO anyway.

I have no clue where Ajax fits into this topic.

Crude and rude (better to reference the library in global.asa to get type info and avoid the long Field ID strings and magic numbers) example copy/pasted and not verified by me:

```
<% 
    sch = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/" 

    Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration") 

    With cdoConfig.Fields 
        .Item(sch & "sendusing") = 2 ' cdoSendUsingPort 
        .Item(sch & "smtpserver") = "<enter_mail.server_here>" 
        .Update 
    End With 

    Set cdoMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 

    With cdoMessage 
        Set .Configuration = cdoConfig 
        .From = "from@me.com" 
        .To = "to@me.com" 
        .Subject = "Sample CDO Message" 
        .TextBody = "This is a test for CDO.message" 
        .Send 
    End With 

    Set cdoMessage = Nothing 
    Set cdoConfig = Nothing 
%>
```

Comment: Ajax I would just use to call the sendMail.aspx?mailid=1  to maybe automate the email function if I can't get it to work in asp.  Otherwise I would just do it directly in asp.  Would you happen to know what the server object is for the CDO email function is in asp?

Comment: Bob, I'm trying to install CDO for use with asp, and I don't see how this link helps unless I'm missing something. thx

Comment: Marc, you don't install CDO for Windows 2000.  It is a system component present in all versions of Windows starting with Win2K.  You asked what the "server object in ASP" was, and the link shows you the CDO classes/interfaces to use.  It isn't a "server object" it is an OS library.

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to add Ajax to ClassicASP? I would say you are asking for trouble. If at all possible, I would encourage the customer to move to .net technology. They will be thankful in the long run.

As far as CDO objects, try out this link [How do I send e-mail with CDO?](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/email/how-do-i-send-e-mail-with-cdo.html)

Comment: Hmm?  What we now call Ajax was pioneered long before there was an ASP.Net.

Comment: That is true. However, in my experience with trying to mix ajax and classic asp, has led to quite a few bug fixes that lasted way past midnight. Just my personal opinion.

Comment: No, I've got CDO to work in vb6, but when trying to get it to work in asp, i'm having trouble.  I don't know how to add a reference for the cdo stuff using asp.  I think it uses windows scripting. thx.

Answer (score 1):

It works this way on ASP Classic using CDO on GoDaddy hosting :

```
<%
Set ObjSendMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="relay-hosting.secureserver.net"
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Update


'ObjSendMail.AddAttachment mPath, "Logo.gif"
'ObjSendMail.AddAttachment ArrwPath, "red_arrw.gif"

ObjSendMail.Subject = strSub
ObjSendMail.To = strTo
ObjSendMail.From = strFrom
ObjSendMail.Bcc = strBcc
ObjSendMail.Cc = strCc
ObjSendMail.HTMLBody = strMsg

ObjSendMail.Send
        Set ObjSendMail = Nothing

%>
```