# ASPX to ASP Conversion (E-mail Script)?

Tags: asp.net, apache, email, asp-classic

I am a `PHP` Developer and I do not have any knowledge about `ASP`. Sadly I am the only developer here and a client had `ASP` (not `ASP.NET`) pages and they wanted a "Contact Us" Form.

I searched the internet to find out how to serve `ASP` files in `Apache` and it pointed me to `mod_aspdotnet`. It was so stupid of me to think that `ASP` is the same as `ASP.NET`! Now do you see my problem? I have developed a working `ASP.NET` email script. The files had `.aspx` extensions but the actual site had `.asp` extensions, they were using `ASP` and not `ASP.NET`!

So I would like to ask for help. This is my email script:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" %>
<%@Import Namespace="System.Web.Mail" %>
<script language="vb" runat="server">

Sub Send2Mail (sender as Object, e as EventArgs)

    Dim objMail as New MailMessage()

    if Logo.HasFile Then
        Try
            Logo.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("uploads/") + Request.form("strName") + "_Logo_" + Logo.FileName)
            objMail.Attachments.Add(new MailAttachment(Server.MapPath("uploads/" + Request.form("strName") + "_Logo_" + Logo.FileName)))
        Catch ex As Exception
            msg.Text = "<b>The Logo could not be uploaded</b>. The following error occured: <i>" + ex.Message + "</i><br />"
            msg.Visible = true
        end try
    end if  

    if Image1.HasFile Then
        Try
            Image1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("uploads/") + Request.form("strName") + "_Image1_" + Image1.FileName)
            objMail.Attachments.Add(new MailAttachment(Server.MapPath("uploads/" + Request.form("strName") + "_Image1_" + Image1.FileName)))
        Catch ex As Exception
            msg.Text = "Image 1 could not be uploaded. The following error occured: <i>" + ex.Message + "</i><br />"
            msg.Visible = true
        end try
    end if  

    if Image2.HasFile Then
        Try
            Image2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("uploads/") + Request.form("strName") + "_Image2_" + Image2.FileName)
            objMail.Attachments.Add(new MailAttachment(Server.MapPath("uploads/" + Request.form("strName") + "_Image2_" + Image2.FileName)))
        Catch ex As Exception
            msg.Text = "Image 2 could not be uploaded. The following error occured: <i>" + ex.Message + "</i><br />"
            msg.Visible = true
        end try
    end if


    objMail.To = "example@example.com"
    objMail.From = """Us"" <do-not-reply@foo.com>"

    objMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html
    objMail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal
    objMail.Subject = "Business Registration"

    objMail.Body = "<html><body style='font-family: Verdana'><table style='font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px'>"
    objMail.Body += "<tr><td><b>Business Name:</b></td><td>" + Request.form("strName") + "</td></tr>"
    objMail.Body += "<tr><td><b>Opening Business Description:</b></td><td>" + Request.form("strOpenDesc") + "</td></tr>"
    objMail.Body += "<tr><td><b>Opening Hours:</b></td><td>" + Request.form("strHours") + "</td></tr>"
    objMail.Body += "<tr><td><b>Business Description:</b></td><td>" + Request.form("strBusDesc") + "</td></tr>"
    objMail.Body += "<tr><td><b>Servicing Area:</b></td><td>" + Request.form("strService") + "</td></tr>"
    objMail.Body += "<tr><td><b>Website Address:</b></td><td>" + Request.form("strWebsite") + "</td></tr>"
    objMail.Body += "<tr><td><b>Email Address:</b></td><td>" + Request.form("strEmail") + "</td></tr>"
    objMail.Body += "<tr><td><b>Telephone Number:</b></td><td>" + Request.form("strPhone") + "</td></tr>"
    objMail.Body += "<tr><td><b>Fax Number:</b></td><td>" + Request.form("strFax") + "</td></tr>"
    objMail.Body += "<tr><td><b>Mobile Phone Number:</b></td><td>" + Request.form("strMobile") + "</td></tr>"
    objMail.Body += "<tr><td><b>Suburb / Post Code:</b></td><td>" + Request.form("strPostCode") + "</td></tr>"
    objMail.Body += "<tr><td><b>Proprietor Name:</b></td><td>" + Request.form("strPropName") + "</td></tr>"
    objMail.Body += "<tr><td><br /></td></tr>"
    objMail.Body += "<tr><td><b>Image 1 Caption:</b></td><td>" + Request.form("strImage1Caption") + "</td></tr>"
    objMail.Body += "<tr><td><b>Image 2 Caption:</b></td><td>" + Request.form("strImage2Caption") + "</td></tr>"
    objMail.Body += "</table><body></html>"

    SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost"

    Try
        SmtpMail.Send(objMail)
        strMessage.Visible = true
    Catch ex As Exception
        msg.Text = "<b>The message was not sent</b>. The following error occured: <i>" + ex.Message + "</i><br />"
        msg.Visible = true
    End Try

End Sub
```

Will this work in `ASP` as it is? What do I need to change to make it work in `ASP`? I am also using the `<asp:></asp:>` tags. Will this work in `ASP`?

**EDIT**

I am sorry for the confusion of what server I am using for development and the host server. The host is using IIS. I am using Apache because I am really a PHP developer. The problem about running ASP pages in Apache was because the client does not want to give me access to their server. They told me that I should just deliver the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ASP` and `ASP.NET` share names for pure marketing reasons but they are basically unrelated technologies, although the latter reuses concepts (such as being a language agnostic framework) and even some method names (such as `Server.MapPath`).

In both ASP's, you have to pick a supported programming language and code your scripts with it. Your sample code seems to use VisualBasic, which was not supported by classic ASP. You'll have to switch to (e.g.) [VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0aew7h6%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Unlike VisualBasic, VBScript is loosely typed, but apart from that it has a similar syntax.

The classic ASP way to send e-mail is the [CDONTS library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526367%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx). A simple example:

```
<%

set mailer = CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")
mailer.from = "foo@example.com"
mailer.to = "bar@example.com"
mailer.subject = "Test e-mail message"
mailer.body = "This is the message body."
mailer.send
set mailer = nothing

%>
```

In general, classic ASP was very similar to PHP: you embed code in your HTML documents.

The difficult part is file upload handling. ASP did not have a native file upload feature: you had to purchase and install a binary commercial library or find one of the VBScript-only code snippets available at the Internet.

**Edit:** Does your client really run ASP over Apache? Microsoft only supports IIS. Apache modules for ASP were normally written by third-parties and often implemented different languages like Perl.

Answer (score 1):

ASP (or Classic ASP as it is now known) and ASP.NET are different beasts. The first is a scripted language similar to PHP, while ASP.NET use the .NET Framework and is compiled to a MSIL binary either before being run and uploaded as a .NET assembly, or on the fly by IIS if the page contains inline script, either way they are then run by the CLR (common language runtime) which forms the core part of the .NET framework.

While some VB.NET code could be converted back to VBScript (the most commonly used Classic ASP language), anything that uses any part of the .NET framework outside of the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace won't be available. To access this kind of functionality you would need to use third party ActiveX/COM components.

You say you want to serve up the ASP script on Apache, is that because you don't have access to an IIS server or that this site that is already running in on Apache? As far as I am aware the only way to run Classic ASP on Apache is to use ChilliSoft/SunOne ASP for Apache. Some hosting companies offer this, but it's a legacy product.

If it is running ChilliSoft ASP then there is a mail component that could be installed, if the host has installed the SpicePack. Take a look at this for more information:

http://developers.sun.com/asp/howto/chilimail.html

http://ns7.webmasters.com/caspdoc/pdf/chilisoft_asp_docs.pdf

I've ported numerous ASP applications from IIS to Apache using ChilliSoft ASP and generally it works very well.

Have a look at this answer for one way on how to send email using ASP: [Sending Mail code in ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772033/sending-mail-code-in-asp)

Failing everything else, just add yourself a page to send the mail in PHP and get the contact form to POST to that page, and then redirect back to an ASP page if you want it to appear seamless.

Comment: Well, the client already has a host. The site is already live and they wanted me to add a Contact form. They do not want to give me access to the host! They said that I should just deliver the files and they will upload it to the host. That is why I was hoping that someone will tell me that I do not actually need to change much in my code. But I guess not. *sigh*

Comment: I just scanned through the HTTP Headers and I saw this: `Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0` and `X-Powered-By: ASP.NET`. Does that mean that they are running `ASP>NET` but the file extensions are `.asp`?

Comment: @Rolando - That probably means that the server can run *both*.

Comment: @Vicario: So I really would not have to worry much if I sent them my current script. Right? Well, thanks I guess I really still have to research classic ASP in case that the server cannot run ASP.NET

Comment: @Rolando To sum up: 1) If you have a Windows box, you can use IIS + ASP or ASP.NET for free. 2) Your customer must tell you the exact specs; you *need* that information to do the job.